# How to bulk move files in C#

Tags: c#, io

I have around 1.5 million files to process

I process these files by taking the top 300 files in my folder, then process and insert them into the database, and then move these files to the archive folder.

the bottleneck in this process is moving files to the archive folder

I am using this code to move the files

```
foreach (string file in Files)
{
    string OutputFileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
    string OutputBackupFile = OutputBackupFolder + OutputFileName;
    MoveWithReplace(file, OutputBackupFile);
}

private void MoveWithReplace(string sourceFileName, string destFileName)
{

    Log("In MoveWithReplace : " + sourceFileName + " to " + destFileName);
    try
    {
        //first, delete target file if exists, as File.Move() does not support overwrite
        if (File.Exists(destFileName))
        {
            File.Delete(destFileName);
        }

        File.Move(sourceFileName, destFileName);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log("ERROR (MoveWithReplace): " + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

I wonder if there is a faster way to move these files in one batch instead of one by one

or a faster way to do the move?

P.S. file size is 100KB on average.

Comment: Your code is perfect, another faster way is folder copy.

Comment: You could try to move the entire directory when you're done using `System.IO.Directory.Move` or you could parallelize the processing of the files so more than 1 file can be moved at once.

Comment: it is 1.5 million files. i cannot  process 1.5 million in one shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try move the files in parallel way with following code

```
Parallel.ForEach(Files, file => { 
  string OutputFileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
    string OutputBackupFile = OutputBackupFolder + OutputFileName;
    MoveWithReplace(file, OutputBackupFile);
});

private static void MoveWithReplace(string sourceFileName, string destFileName)
{

    Log("In MoveWithReplace : " + sourceFileName + " to " + destFileName);
    try
    {
        //first, delete target file if exists, as File.Move() does not support overwrite
        if (File.Exists(destFileName))
        {
            File.Delete(destFileName);
        }

        File.Move(sourceFileName, destFileName);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log("ERROR (MoveWithReplace): " + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

I had not tried compile it

Comment: what exactly did you change on this code?

Comment: only replaced foreach by Parallel.ForEach and made method MoveWithReplace static